# Multi-column file parsing with Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a four columns text file and want to create two vectors with it. 
I intend to use the first and second columns as a mixed index.
So the first and second columns are integer and 3rd and 4th are double. 
In FORTRAN it would be:

```
10 READ("4Column_file.txt",*,END=20)N,M,T1,T2
   IG=(N*(N+1))/2+M+1
   CC(IG)=T1
   CS(IG)=T2
   GOTO 10 
20 CONTINUE
```

How I do it with Kotlin or Java?

The input is in the form:

```
5   5  -0.244048470535508183D+00  -0.129800076712784507D+01
6   0  -0.468652527040705080D+01   0.000000000000000000D+00
```

The output would be CC[IG] and CS[IG] vectors loaded.

For example in the first line: 
 `IG=(5*(5+1))/2+5+1=21` 
so CC[21]=-0.244048470535508183D+00 and CS[21]=-0.129800076712784507D+01.

In the second line:
 `IG=(6*(6+1))/2+5+1=27` 
so CC[27]=-0.468652527040705080D+01 and CS[27]=0.000000000000000000D+00

Comment: Could you give an example of the input file, as well as the output you expect for that input?

Comment: Edited with needed input and output

Comment: That read statement isn't Fortran. And if you want to use Fortran as an example it would be better to use a more modern style rather than one from the 1980s, it would make you question more accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Kotlin:

```
val length = 20 // Some default length
val cc = arrayOfNulls<String>(length)
val cs = arrayOfNulls<String>(length)

val lineRegex = "\\s+".toRegex()

File("4Column_file.txt").useLines { lineSequence ->
    for (line in lineSequence) {
        val (n, m, t1, t2) = line.split(lineRegex)
        val nInt = n.toInt()
        val mInt = m.toInt()

        val ig = (nInt * (nInt + 1)) / 2 + mInt + 1
        cc[ig] = t1
        cs[ig] = t2
    }
}
```

If you don't know the length beforehand, you would need to read all the lines into some data class first. You then need find the maximum value of `ig`, and create the arrays of that size. Something like:

```
data class Row(val n: Int, val m: Int, val t1: String, val t2: String) {
    val ig: Int = (n * (n + 1)) / 2 + m + 1
}

// rowList is List<Row> after parsing
val maxIdx = rowList.maxBy { it.ig } ?: -1

val cc = arrayOfNulls<String>(maxIdx + 1)
val cs = arrayOfNulls<String>(maxIdx + 1)

for (row in rowList) {
    cc[row.ig] = row.t1
    cs[row.ig] = row.t2
}
```

Comment: "4Column_file.txt" was on only a example file name. I'm using File(resources.getResourceName(R.raw.corrc)).useLines as my file name inside row folder is "corrc" without extension. But I'm receiving file.not.found exceptions. Do you know why?

Comment: @Newton_Jose You probably get another path than you expect. You should check the return value of `resources.getResourceName(R.raw.corrc)`.

Comment: It's give me "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: newton.egm96:raw/corrc (No such file or directory)". Must be a missing slash(/)?

Comment: @Newton_Jose Maybe, just try it. I don't know how your file system is structured.

Comment: I resolve the filename question. But the splitter is not working. I manage to run the code in line command and it give me `m=  n=360 c1=360 c2=0.205445744870012291E-17` So it is jumping the variable m (the first one). I try another forms for regexp but none works. Could you help me?

Comment: @Newton_Jose Try trimming the line first... `line.trim().split(lineRegex)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [univocity-parsers](https://github.com/univocity/univocity-parsers). There is a tutorial about parsing tab separated files:

https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tsv.html#working-with-tsv

Since Kotlin is running on the JVM and is [100% interoperable with Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#is-kotlin-compatible-with-the-java-programming-language), you can simply include the [univocity-parsers jar as dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.univocity/univocity-parsers/2.8.2) instead of coding it yourself - here the Maven coordinates:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
  <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I really wanted this to work, but I had trouble integrating this with Kotlin. It would parse without error but the properties for every row were null. I tried with both data classes and mutable classes with a parameterless constructor. Have you used univocity in Kotlin before? How did you make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure, if univocity-parsers work with Kotlin data classes. My answer refers to the parsing capability e.g. List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(...) - you would then have to map the String array yourself to a data class.

Comment: I got it working with data classes by the way. Univocity needs a no arg constructor, which you can accomplish with default arguments. Every field has to start set to null. Univocity fills them with java reflection, likewise you can still use vals. So it's a little weird but it works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks @DrewNutter that helped me get it working.