# Convert text file to map?

Tags: kotlin, text

How can you **convert text file** with many *(about 15000)* values **separated** with **lines**, each with **150 values separated** **by tabstops** into a *map* (**key**: one of the 150 values, **value**: all 150 values) in **kotlin**?

Searched and found solutions for primitive (one key, one value) text files, but not for more complex like my case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400571/multi-column-file-parsing-with-kotlin

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What have you tried? Do you have an example of the data you're trying to parse? Are you asking how to parse a tab-separated file? If so, have you considered using a library? https://github.com/doyaaaaaken/kotlin-csv https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe